# How to check a date satisfies a cron pattern in cron4j

Tags: cron4j

In Quartz, we can tell if a date satisfies a cron pattern by calling CronExpression.isSatisfiedBy(date).

May I know how to do the same in cron4j?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a

```
static boolean validate(java.lang.String schedulingPattern)
```

on the SchedulingPattern class.

Answer (score 2):

The method is SchedulingPattern.match(millis)